# Pyspark how to count the number of occurences of a string in each group and print multiple selected columns?

Tags: python, pyspark, aggregate, data-science

My data set looks like this. Each row represents a car. Each car is located at an `Auto Center`, has a `Model`, `Make`, and a bunch of other attributes. This is a simplified version of the data frame. Extraneous rows and columns have been omitted for clarity.

```
+===========+========+=======+====+=====+
|Auto Center|Model   |Make   |Year|Color|
+===========+========+=======+====+=====+
|Roseville  |Corolla |Toyota |    |     |
|Roseville  |Prius   |Toyota |    |     |
|Rocklin    |Camry   |Toyota |    |     |
|Rocklin    |Forester|Subaru |    |     |
+===========+========+=======+====+=====+
```

What do I want to do? I want to group the data by the `Auto Center`, and display a "list" of the top 5 cars in each `Auto Center` by quantify, and print their attributes `Make`, `Model`, `Year`, and `Color`.

After grouping the data by the `Auto Center`, I want to count the number of occurrences of each `Model`, or even better a combination of `Make` and `Model`, in each `Auto Center`, and I want to get a list of the top 5 cars with the most occurrences. Then I want to print multiple columns of that car.

Assume that the `Year` and the `Color` are the same for each car having the same `Make` and `Model`.

For example, the output should be something like this, a list of the top 5 cars in each auto center ordered by the number of occurrences.

```
Rosevile:
there are 12 red Toyota Prius 2009
there are 8 blue Toyota Cary 2010
 ...
```

This is what I have so far:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, IntegerType, StringType

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
scSpark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Auto Center Big Data") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = scSpark.read.csv("autocenters.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)
data.printSchema();

data.groupby('Auto Center')
```

It seems that `data.groupby()` returns a `GroupedData` object. I have seem that `.agg()` function can be applied to it, but that only works for *numerical* data, such as finding the mean of some numbers, and here I have strings. I want to count the strings by number of occurrences in each group.

What should I do? Is there a way to apply an aggregate function to multiple columns simultaneously, such as both `Make` and `Model` together? If not, that should be fine though, considering that there are no cars with the same `Model` having different `Make`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do it with the following two steps:

1. First groupby all columns you want to count on the occurences:

   ```
   df1 = df.groupby('Auto Center', 'Model', 'Make', 'Year', 'Color').count()
   ```
2. Then set up a Window Spec and get the top **5** by row_number():
   (**Note:** depends on how you want to handle ties, you might want to change the function *row_number()* to *rank()* or *dense_rank()*)

   ```
   from pyspark.sql import Window
   from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, desc

   w1 = Window.partitionBy('Auto Center').orderBy(desc('count'))

   df_new = df1.withColumn('rn', row_number().over(w1)).where('rn <= 5').drop('rn')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

import pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('local')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

then create a random dataframe similar to yours

```
import string
import random

n = 1000
center = ['center_{}'.format(random.choice(string.ascii_letters[:2])) for y in range(n)]
make = ['make_{}'.format(random.choice(string.ascii_letters[:3])) for y in range(n)]
model = ['model_{}'.format(random.choice(string.ascii_letters[:3])) for y in range(n)]
year = [random.choice(range(2018, 2019)) for y in range(n)]
color = [random.choice(['red', 'blue', 'black']) for y in range(n)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(center, make, model, year, color), schema=['center', 'make', 'model', 'year', 'color'])

df.head()

Row(center='center_b', make='make_a', model='model_c', year=2018, color='black')
```

group by center, make, model, year, color

```
df_groupby = (df
              .groupby('center', 'make', 'model', 'year', 'color')
              .count()
             )
df_groupby.sort(df_groupby['center'],
                df_groupby['count'].desc()).show()

+--------+------+-------+----+-----+-----+
|  center|  make|  model|year|color|count|
+--------+------+-------+----+-----+-----+
|center_a|make_c|model_b|2018| blue|   33|
|center_a|make_a|model_c|2018| blue|   24|
|center_a|make_a|model_a|2018|  red|   23|
|center_a|make_b|model_c|2018| blue|   21|
|center_a|make_b|model_b|2018|black|   21|
|center_a|make_c|model_a|2018|black|   21|
|center_a|make_c|model_c|2018| blue|   21|
|center_a|make_a|model_c|2018|black|   20|
|center_a|make_a|model_b|2018|  red|   20|
|center_a|make_a|model_b|2018| blue|   19|
|center_a|make_c|model_c|2018|black|   18|
|center_a|make_a|model_c|2018|  red|   18|
|center_a|make_c|model_b|2018|  red|   18|
|center_a|make_b|model_b|2018|  red|   18|
|center_a|make_c|model_a|2018|  red|   18|
|center_a|make_a|model_b|2018|black|   18|
|center_a|make_b|model_c|2018|black|   18|
|center_a|make_a|model_a|2018| blue|   17|
|center_a|make_c|model_a|2018| blue|   17|
|center_a|make_c|model_b|2018|black|   15|
+--------+------+-------+----+-----+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

using a Window, keep only the top 5 make/model/color/year per center

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, desc

w = Window.partitionBy('center').orderBy(desc('count'))
df_groupby2 = df_groupby.withColumn('rn', row_number().over(w)).where('rn <= 5').drop('rn')

df_groupby2.sort(df_groupby2['center'],
                 df_groupby2['count'].desc()
                ).show()

+--------+------+-------+----+-----+-----+
|  center|  make|  model|year|color|count|
+--------+------+-------+----+-----+-----+
|center_a|make_c|model_b|2018| blue|   33|
|center_a|make_a|model_c|2018| blue|   24|
|center_a|make_a|model_a|2018|  red|   23|
|center_a|make_b|model_b|2018|black|   21|
|center_a|make_c|model_a|2018|black|   21|
|center_b|make_a|model_a|2018|  red|   31|
|center_b|make_c|model_c|2018|black|   24|
|center_b|make_b|model_a|2018| blue|   24|
|center_b|make_b|model_b|2018|black|   23|
|center_b|make_c|model_c|2018| blue|   23|
+--------+------+-------+----+-----+-----+
```

now create and print your text

```
df_final = (df_groupby2
            .withColumn('text', F.concat(F.lit("there are "),
                                         df_groupby2['count'],
                                         F.lit(" "),
                                         df_groupby2['color'],
                                         F.lit(" "),
                                         df_groupby2['make'],
                                         F.lit(" "),
                                         df_groupby2['model'],
                                         F.lit(" "),
                                         df_groupby2['year'])
                       )
            .sort(df_groupby2['center'],
                 df_groupby2['count'].desc()
                )
           )

for row in df_final.select('center').distinct().sort('center').collect():
    current_center = row['center']
    print(current_center, ":")
    for row in df_final.filter(df_final['center'] == current_center).collect():
        print(row['text'])

center_a :
there are 33 blue make_c model_b 2018
there are 24 blue make_a model_c 2018
there are 23 red make_a model_a 2018
there are 21 black make_b model_b 2018
there are 21 black make_c model_a 2018
center_b :
there are 31 red make_a model_a 2018
there are 24 blue make_b model_a 2018
there are 24 black make_c model_c 2018
there are 23 black make_b model_b 2018
there are 23 blue make_c model_c 2018
```